# How to transfer photos from my iPad to Mac

Tags: mac, photos, ipad, transfer

One of the great benefits of the iPad will be putting a ton of my photos in one, great place to show friends and family (rather than bringing them over to my computer). But I have several thousand photos, all organized on my iPad in folders by year and subject.I would like to transfer them to my mac? How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Its questions like this that make me wonder why people like apple so much. I have a Android phone. I can plug my usb cord into my computer and browse my phone like it is any other disk. Heck I can even do it with blue-tooth. No jail-breaken or extra software needed.

Answer (score 2):

How to upload pictures previously stored on a iPad but cannot use iTunes or windows explorer to extract them back to the PC for some reason? As long as you can see them on the iPad, you can get them back onto the PC. Here is how:

It will take time depending on how many pictures you need to transfer, but if you are like me, time is worth the wait.

1. Sign up with an internet photo album website like Picasa
2. Download the app Picasa web album to the iPad
3. Start uploading your pics thru the app to the web
4. Once you have uploaded a few or all of your pictures to the web, log in to your account on the PC / computer
5. Download the pictures from the web directly onto your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

1- **If your iPad is jailbroken**, you can either ssh into it from a local computer and copy all the files. Or you can get a utility to view the filsystem of the iPad and transfer the folder manually.

2- **If your iPad isn't jailbroken**, you could purchase the ssh app and do the same as above. You could also buy something like GoodReader which will allow you to share files and photos. Another option is Apple's photo connector kit for iPad http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC531ZM/A

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out "[iMacsoft iPad to Mac Transfer](http://www.imacsoft.com/ipad-to-mac-transfer.html)".  Never used it personally, and it's not free, but may be worth the $25 to you.

> When you lost the iTunes music or when you want to backup your iPad collection on Mac in case files are damaged or crashed, you need a iPad to Mac transfer to copy iPad to Mac, backup iPad to Mac. iMacsoft iPad to Mac Transfer makes you transfer Music, Movie, Photo, ePub, PDF, Audiobook, Camera Roll, Podcast and TV Show from iPad to Mac. Moreover, you can freely copy iPad files to iTunes library, add Mac files to iPad.